# Principles of Quantum Mechanics

Tags: solution-verification

[image: Principles of Quantum Mechanics]

I have asked this question all over reddit but can't seem to find an answer. I hope it's not the same here.

How do you get from equation one to equation two? I have tried so many methods but couldn't get the same answer.

I tried $E^{2} = m^{2}c^{4} + p^{2}c^{2}$ but got a different term in the radical of
$$
cp' = h\left(\omega + \omega'\right) \pm \sqrt{h\omega' - m^{2}c^{4}}
$$

Could someone show me the steps for how you get the initial and final momentum $?$.

Comment: You can read a [MSE MathJax Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to improve your questions. Try to avoid images. People expect you explain the whole problem without inserting images. In that way, chances you get answers are increasing.

Comment: I think this might belong in Physics StackExchange.